# xdomain.js and browserify don't work

Tags: browserify, xdomainrequest

I am trying to integrate xdomain.js with browserify :

```
require('xdomain/dist/0.6/xdomain');
```

but i get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: xhook is not defined
  (anonymous function)  xdomain.js:882
  (anonymous function)  xdomain.js:1067
```

the only solution is to concat script files or include script in html (which is not acceptable cause component needs to be independent of external dependencies)

is there a way to integrate xdomain.js using standard browserify mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need a [`browserify-shim`](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) configuration so that you can pull in the `xhook` dependency. e.g. in your `package.json`:

```
  //...
  "browser": {
    "xdomain": "xdomain/dist/0.6/xdomain.js",
    "xhook": "xdomain/vendor/xhook.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "xhook": {
      "exports": "xhook"
    },
    "xdomain": {
      "exports": "xdomain",
      "depends": ["xhook"]
    }
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
  },
  //...
```

And of course you'll have to install the `browserify-shim` package with npm.

Comment: modified package like you wrote, build, nothing changed - xhook is not defined. Tried to require 'xhook', 'xdomain' - no browserify errors but still 'no xhook defined'. No clue.